# Gitlab pipeline error when building quarkus project and dockerizing it

Tags: docker, gitlab, quarkus

I wrote a simple pipeline in gitlab to build a quarkus project, to dockerize it and to push the final image to a registry.
Here it is:

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - build-package-dockerize
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -y -qq build-essential libz-dev zlib1g-dev

build, package, dockerize:
  stage: build-package-dockerize
  script:
    - mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dquarkus.profile=dev -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true -Dquarkus.container-image.push=true -Dquarkus.container-image.group=pss -Dquarkus.container-image.tag=$CI_BUILD_REF -Dquarkus.container-image.registry=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_AZURE_URL -Dquarkus.container-image.username=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_AZURE_USERNAME -Dquarkus.container-image.password=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_AZURE_PASSWORD 
  only:
    - DEV
```

When the pipe runs it returns error in ryuk container deployment:

```
[INFO] Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3 is starting: 2611772cb72f4f2437ee1c405243d7519dfe787d8a0f343b292e8b2db4aa4869
1745[ERROR] Could not start container
1746java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container is removed
[ERROR] There are no stdout/stderr logs available for the failed container
1777[WARNING] [io.quarkus.deployment.IsDockerWorking] No docker binary found or general error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Input/Output error while executing command.
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many times doing it with docker but it was a mess (cause Docker in docker). I believe you have the same problem because your error states that `No docker binary found`.

My solution would be easier, try with Jib. Quarkus supports it by default and it's much easier to use, see my example :

```yaml
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - build-package-dockerize
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -y -qq build-essential libz-dev zlib1g-dev

build-package-dockerize:
  stage: build-package-dockerize
  script:
    - mvn clean package
      -DskipTests
      -Dquarkus.profile=dev
# Instruct Quarkus to use Jib
      -Dquarkus.container-image.builder=jib
# Don't forget to add token file to repo, otherwise you'll get http 401 when pushing
      -Dquarkus.jib.to.auth.username=gitlab-ci-token
      -Dquarkus.jib.to.auth.password=${CI_TOKEN_PASSWORD}
      -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true
      -Dquarkus.container-image.push=true
      -Dquarkus.container-image.group=pss
      -Dquarkus.container-image.tag=$CI_BUILD_REF
      -Dquarkus.container-image.registry=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_AZURE_URL 
      -Dquarkus.container-image.username=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_AZURE_USERNAME
      -Dquarkus.container-image.password=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_AZURE_PASSWORD 
  only:
    - DEV
```

I'm using it right now for multiple projects, and its working perfectly.

For reference, you can find every Jib params here [Quarkus Jib](https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#jib-options)

Comment: Mate, I love you. You solved my problem. Sure it is a bit difficult to fit quarkus in gitlab but your solution works well. A big thank you

Comment: @Giamma No problem bro, more than happy to help. Don't forget to accept my answer if it fitted the question